# Dependency Injection issue - controller being required to have constructor with no parameters

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I'm getting the "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" error.  This has come up before but nothing I've seen resolves the issue for me.  Is there something about the way I am doing DI here that would cause this error?

in my controller:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{

 private readonly IStuff stuff;

 public NameController(IStuff stuff)
 {
   this.stuff = stuff;
 }


 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    NameModel model = stuff.GetNameModel();   
    return View(model);  
 }
```

}

in my AutofacConfig.cs:

```
    public static ContainerBuilder GetBuilder()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register<Idb>(c => new db(...);
        builder.RegisterType<Stuff>().As<IStuff>();
    }
```

in Global.asax.cs:

```
    private void BuildContainer()
    {
        var builder =  AutofacConfig.GetBuilder();
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

the stuff class:

```
public interface IStuff
{

    NameModel GetNameModel();

}


 public class Stuff
{
    private readonly Idb db;

    public Stuff(Idb db)
    {
        this.db = db;


    }


    public NameModel GetNameModel()
    {
        NameModel modelobject = new NameModel();

        modelobject.info = "info";

        return modelobject ;

    }
 }
```

Here is the exception message...

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +239
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '....NameController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +102
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +188
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: How about a default constructor `public NameController(){}` with *no parameters*.

Comment: Provide a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Is that needed?  It should always use the constructor with parameters.  I thought this meant I wasn't resolving it properly.

Comment: As suspected, if I add an empty constructor then it uses it by default and the attempt to call the interface method crashes.

Comment: Which type is it actually complaining about - `NameController` or `Stuff`? Since it's presumably `Stuff` would you please post that classes definition? And kindly post the full exception message?

Comment: Just added the exception message.

Comment: Can you add the code for the Stuff class? Like @RB mentioned, this can happen when a required dependency constructor requires dependencies that aren't configured

Comment: Just added the stuff class

Answer (score 0):

if you added/upgraded new dll version, make sure that dll existing in Web.config. if you didn't add anything new then add all package to web.config and try it will work.